# In R, apply a sequence of complex functions using the "do" function in dplyr

Tags: r

I would like to know that if is possible apply a sequence of especial functions using pipe chaining. For example, supose that I have the following data with 3 levels in group_var:

```
head(df)
 v1  v2 .... v9  group_var
  1   2       0          1
  5   3       2          0 
  2   1       3          1 
  1   8       9          2
  7   6       0          1
  5   9       2          0
```

My firs question: I wish do the following

```
res<- df %>% group_by(group_var) %>% do( out = special_function(.) )
```

where the special function has diferents components functions for each group. That is, in pseudocode, the special function is

```
special_function = (f0,f1,f2)
```

so that *f1, f2, f3* are mutually diferents. For example

```
f0<- function(data) apply(data, 2, min)
f1<- function(data) t(data)
f2<- function(data) as.list(data)
```

and

```
df[df$group_var == i ,]
```

is the input of the *fi*  function for each *i = 0,1,2*. That is

```
res$out[[1]] ==  f0(df[df$group_var == 0 ,])
> T 
res$out[[2]] ==  f0(df[df$group_var == 1 ,])
> T
res$out[[3]] ==  f0(df[df$group_var == 2 ,])
> T
```

My second question is related to my first question. If the response of the first question is yes, I would like apply more operations. Actually, I want use the outputs of each *fi* and apply operations one related to other. For example

```
other_special_function<- function(d1,d2,d3)
{
ret<- cbind(d1 , d2)
ret2<- cbind(ret, apply(d,2,sum))
return(ret2)
}

res2<- res %>% do(out2 = other_special_function(.) )
```

Which

```
res2$out2 = other_special_function(res$out[[1]], res$out[[2]] , res$out[[3]] )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You absolutely can do this with pipes and functions; it is very flexible. If you have a function in mind that might be more complicated, as you describe, I would recommend going with purrr and `map()` rather than `do()` from dplyr.

Let's say you have everybody's favorite iris dataset. You can start out by using `nest()` from tidyr so that you have one row per group, with the data nested into mini-dataframes in a list-column.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

iris %>% 
    nest(-Species) 

#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>      Species              data
#>       <fctr>            <list>
#> 1     setosa <tibble [50 × 4]>
#> 2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]>
#> 3  virginica <tibble [50 × 4]>
```

Then say you have some arbitrary function that you want to apply to each little mini-dataframe, and it is different depending on what the species is. This could be as complicated as you like.

```r
fun <- function(df, species) {
    if (species == "setosa") {
        t(df)
    } else {
        df
    }
}
```

You can use `map2()` from purrr to apply this function to each species/data pair, and you can put it in a new column in the data frame, and keep going, if you'd like.

```r
library(purrr)

iris %>% 
    nest(-Species) %>%
    mutate(output = map2(data, Species, fun))

#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>      Species              data            output
#>       <fctr>            <list>            <list>
#> 1     setosa <tibble [50 × 4]>    <dbl [4 × 50]>
#> 2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]> <tibble [50 × 4]>
#> 3  virginica <tibble [50 × 4]> <tibble [50 × 4]>
```

This is a flexible technique for applying arbitrary operations to data, and is especially [great for modeling](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html).